# How to fix this malformed xml using php and write the file to my server

Tags: php, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tv><channel id="Nick Jr.">
    <display-name lang="en">Nick Jr. MX</display-name><icon src="Nick Jr..png" />
    <url>http://www.my.tv</url>
  </channel><channel id="The NFL Network ">
    <display-name lang="en">The NFL Network </display-name><icon src="The NFL Network .png" />
    <url>http://www.my.tv</url>
  </channel><channel id="ESPN">
    <display-name lang="en">ESPN</display-name><icon src="ESPN.png" />
    <url>http://www.my.tv</url>
  </channel><channel id="ESPN News">
    <display-name lang="en">ESPN News</display-name><icon src="ESPN News.png" />
    <url>http://www.my.tv</url>
  </channel><channel id="ESPNU">
    <display-name lang="en">ESPNU</display-name><icon src="ESPNU.png" />
    <url>http://www.my.tv</url>
  </channel><channel id="ESPN2">
    <display-name lang="en">ESPN2</display-name><icon src="ESPN2.png" />
    <url>http://www.my.tv</url>
  </channel><channel id="The NFL Network">
    <display-name lang="en">The NFL Network</display-name><icon src="The NFL Network.png" />
    <url>http://www.my.tv</url>
  </channel><channel id="MLB Network">
    <display-name lang="en">MLB Network</display-name><icon src="MLB Network.png" />
    <url>http://www.my.tv</url>
  </channel><channel id="MavTV">
    <display-name lang="en">MavTV</display-name><icon src="MavTV.png" />
    <url>http://www.my.tv</url>
  </channel>
</tv>
```

This the xml. Normally this will on get from a url. like for example
url = 'http://hello.com/myxml.xml

I wanna make a php script that fix this xml And rewrite fixed xml to my server(localhost)

And help?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: How is that xml malformed, it looks fine to me?

Comment: Not tried any. I cannot find a correct one. Yes it was malformed   </channel><channel id="MavTV"> see this tag not wanna be like this

Comment: Your XML isn't broken, why do you want to fix it? What output do you want to produce from this input?

Comment: It was broken </channel><channel id="The NFL Network "> in these places it wanna be seperated. If u put this to my xml to xml validator u will see. </channel> from here it wanna be seperated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML is not malformed. It is perfectly fine. Here is not even a notice/warning.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors();
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
var_dump(libxml_get_errors());
```

Output:

```
array(0) {
}
```

I think you might want reformat the XML. You can do this with DOM.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
$document->loadXml($xml);
echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tv>
  <channel id="Nick Jr.">
    <display-name lang="en">Nick Jr. MX</display-name>
    <icon src="Nick Jr..png"/>
    <url>http://www.my.tv</url>
  </channel>
  <channel id="The NFL Network ">
    <display-name lang="en">The NFL Network </display-name>
    <icon src="The NFL Network .png"/>
    <url>http://www.my.tv</url>
  </channel>
  ...
```

Comment: Yes that was what I looking for. Great. plz tell me how to load http://www.idragonlk.com/c3-e8gvsn.xml this url and get reformatted.

Comment: Load it into a string using `file_get_contents()` or directly with `DOMDocument::load()`.

Comment: Plz tell me a way to replace string of that xml file before it echo?

Comment: Oh found it $xml = str_replace("&amp;"," and ",$xml); Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/zh/book.simplexml.php) library analysis, and rewrite fixed xml to your server

[image]